# Matlab - Algorithm for calculating 1d consecutive line segment edges from midpoints?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, cell, mesh

So I have a rectilinear grid that can be described with 2 vectors. 1 for the x-coordinates of the cell centres and one for the y-coordinates. These are just points with spacing like x spacing is 50 scaled to 10 scaled to 20 (55..45..30..10,10,10..10,12..20,20,20) and y spacing is 60 scaled to 40 scaled to 60 (60,60,60,55..42,40,40,40..40,42..60,60) and the grid is made like this

```
e.g. x = 1 2 3, gridx = 1 2 3, y = 10 11 12, gridy = 10 10 10 
                        1 2 3                        11 11 11
                        1 2 3                        12 12 12
```

so then cell centre 1 is 1,10 cc2 is 2,10 etc.

Now Im trying to formulate an algorithm to calculate the positions of the cell edges in the x and y direction. So like my first idea was to first get the first edge using x(1)-[x(2)-x(1)]/2, in the real case x(2)-x(1) is equal to 60 and x(1) = 16348.95 so celledge1 = x(1)-30 = 16318.95. Then after calculating the first one I go through a loop and calculate the rest like this:

```
for aa = 2:length(x)+1
    celledge1(aa) = x(aa-1) + [x(aa-1)-celledge(aa-1)]
end
```

And I did the same for y. This however does not work and my y vector in the area where the edge spacing should be should be 40 is 35,45,35,45... approx.

Anyone have any idea why this doesnt work and can point me in the right direction. Cheers

Edit: Tried to find a solution using geometric alebra:

[image]

We are trying to find the points A,B,C,....H. From basic geometry we know:

```
c1 (centre 1) = [A+B]/2 and c2 = [B+C]/2 etc. etc.
```

So we have 7 equations and 8 variables. We also know the the first few distances between centres are equal (60,60,60,60) therefore the first segment is 60 too.

```
B - A = 60
```

So now we have 8 equations and 8 variables so I made this algorithm in Matlab:

```
edgex = zeros(length(DATA2.x)+1,1);
edgey = zeros(length(DATA2.y)+1,1);

edgex(1) = (DATA2.x(1)*2-diffx(1))/2;
edgey(1) = (DATA2.y(1)*2-diffy(1))/2;

for aa = 2:length(DATA2.x)+1
    edgex(aa) = DATA2.x(aa-1)*2-edgex(aa-1);
end

for aa = 2:length(DATA2.y)+1
    edgey(aa) = DATA2.y(aa-1)*2-edgey(aa-1);
end
```

And I still got the same answer as before with the y spacing going 35,45,35,45 where it should be 40,40,40... Could it be an accuracy error??

Edit: here are the numbers if ur interested and I did the same computation as above only in excel: http://www.filedropper.com/workoutedges

Comment: I wonder if this is relevant to your problem, but check the [`voronoi`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html) function, and its background. I believe they have a function to calculate vertices. However, sorry if it is not appropriate.

Comment: You lost me on the second line. What does "like x spacing is 50 scaled to 10 scaled to 20" mean? How did you get the values "(55..45..30..10,10,10..10,12..20,20,20)" from that? What are the missing values? I think this question could be simplified a lot by simply carrying through the calculations for your sample data. You've got a lot of random bits about what doesn't work, but nothing I can see that says exactly what the results you want are.

Comment: @beaker thats just the distances between the midpoints, so the first couple of midpoints are 50 apart and then they are scaled down to 20, so the spacing gets smaller incrementally down to 20 and its 20 for a number of midpoints then scaled down to 10, then scales back to 20. All I want is to calculate a set of numbers between my midpoints for which between each the midpoint is the exact centre.

Comment: So, scaling is just what happens to the data? Why is this necessary to know in order to solve the problem? From what I can see, this is simply interpolation (with extrapolation for the endpoints), right? It would be *extremely* helpful if you posted a sample data set and the desired results for that data set.

Comment: @beaker I did its at the bottom. An excel sheet. The only necessity is that all the midpoints are in the exact middle of the edge points.

Comment: Links die. Please add a *small* sample data set to your question. I'll make up some data in the mean time and try to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're just trying to interpolate your data. You can do this with the built-in [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)

```
x = [30 24 19 16 8 7 16 22 29 31];
xi = interp1(2:2:numel(x)*2, x, 1:(numel(x)*2+1), 'linear', 'extrap');
```

This just sets up the original data as the *even*-indexed elements and interpolates the *odd* indices, including extrapolation for the two end points.

Results:

```
xi =

 Columns 1 through 11:

   33.0000   30.0000   27.0000   24.0000   21.5000   19.0000   17.5000   16.0000   12.0000    8.0000    7.5000

 Columns 12 through 21:

    7.0000   11.5000   16.0000   19.0000   22.0000   25.5000   29.0000   30.0000   31.0000   32.0000
```